# Подскажите каким способом и какими библиотеками решить задачу. Python

Tags: python

Что имеем на входе: 10+ одинаковых окон с одинаковым названием процесса. На всех окнах почти одна и та же картинка. Разница только в доминирующем цвете. На половине окон доминирует желто-оранжевый цвет. На другой половине - сине-голубой. Мне нужно разделить эти окна между собой и добавить их в список. Каким способом это лучше всего сделать? Какие библиотеки использовать? Скринить каждое окно и работать со скрином? Или можно работать напрямую с окном? На данный момент уже использую библиотеку pywinauto для переключения между окнам. Также везде +- одинаковая картинка. Т.е. можно будет сравнивать с уже готовым скрином. Например, если схожесть с референсом высокая - пушим в один лист, низкая - в другой.
Если будет возможность показать какой-либо код, буду рад. Спасибо. Язык - Python